# why for(class A{} fkldsjflksdjflsj;;) can compile?

Tags: c++, syntax

I placed something wrong in a for loop, but it seems it can still compile. Then I tried the for loop syntax, and it seems the following code: a class definition inside start condition in for loop with some meaningless characters like this, can compile.

```
int main(){
    for(class A{} fkldsjflksdjflsj;;)
    return 0;
}
```

Also.

```
for(class A;;)
for(class A{};;)
```

But not.

```
for(class A fkldsjflksdjflsj;;)
```

Why?

Comment: You can write any *simple-declaration* there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first part of a `for` may contain a variable declaration. (And some other types of declaration). Luckily that is what we have:

```
class A
{
} zzz;
```

declares a variable `zzz` whose type is `class A` which is a class with no user-defined members.

`class A fkldsjflksdjflsj` fails because `class A` is not defined. But it would be OK if you had defined `class A` earlier.

Comment: Making it a pointer would work `class A* a` but that's probably not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared an instance of class `A` named `fkldsjflksdjflsj`, within the for-loop scope. The `class A fkldsjflksdjflsj` declaration fails because you did not specify a class body.

Answer (score 0):

`fkldsjflksdjflsj` is not 'some meaningless characters'. It is the name of a variable of type `class A` which you have also just declared, via the syntax `class A {}`. So the whole thing is a variable-declaration, which is exactly what the first part of the `for` statement requires.